# Сервис для хранения любых файлов с версионностью текстовых файлов?

Tags: файлы, версионность

Мне нужен сервис объединяющий git и яндекс диск. 
То есть единая папка на всех моих компьютерах где можно хранить какие угодно файлы мультимедиа, но при этом чтобы текстовые файлы, как то версионировались и это было бы удобно смотреть и извлекать предыдущие версии.

Git если там хранить картинки и видео перестаёт работать когда размер репозитория превышает 1-2 гб и тормозит жутко.

Установил яндекс диск, но там нет версий файлов, только можно просмотреть историю файла.

Получается яндекс диск еще хуже, так как при порче или ошибках файла распространит это на остальные устройства.

Comment: Google Drive поддерживает версионность. А на гите картинки и видео можно хранить в отдельном репозитории

Comment: Хочется чтобы была 1 папка. Там удобней всего, а не несколько  разных программ или репозиториев.

Comment: гугл диск посмотрели?

Comment: Гугл диск посмотрел, сейчас пользуюсь. Но там написано что версии файлов хранятся 30 дней, а потом удаляются. А хотелось бы надежный инструмент, когда текстовые файлы хранятся вечно.

Comment: Может скрестить гугл и гит? На гугле хранить все и с него синхронизироваться,. на гите хранить только текстовые файлы

Comment: Вот это как раз и не удобно. 
Смысл в том чтобы на рабочем, домашнем компе, ноутбуке, телефоне и.т.д был единый доступ к данным и положив туда файл и редактируя я бы не боялся что он пропадёт или я забуду куда его положил.

Comment: А как в google диск на другом компьютере просмотреть папку которую расшарил на предыдущем?